# Need guidance on logo redesign for hobby site

Tags: website-design, logo

I'm a non-graphics guy who runs a player-finder website for tabletop gamers.  I'm not happy with the site's current logo but don't know what to do about it.

[image: Current Logo]

The current logo at the top of the front page has a lot of elements in the logo to show we are inclusive to the various types of tabletop games. Unfortunately many of these groups tend to be isolated from each other. So I wanted to make sure these groups know they are supported by my site.

With logo redesign in mind, should I try to stay inclusive and keep similar elements in the logo? Should I have fewer elements?

If you want to look at the site for reference, it's at https://www.findgamers.us

Comment: It's not really a logo. It's a banner, but other than the name, there's nothing particularly unique about the assorted visuals. So, at this point, you're asking "how do I design a logo" that, while a good question, is simply way too broad for this Q/A web site. I'd suggest googling this topic as there is a lot written on it out there. Beyond that, look at lots of logos. Figure out what logos appeal to you and *why* they appeal to you.

Comment: I see that now, this stuff is new to me.  I'm taking everything said on this page seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's a logo, it's far too complex and detailed for being remembered.

I am suggesting a combination of two well-known elements. If you're googling for the term "find" and look at the images result, you'll find that it's commonly represented by a magnifier glass. Doing the same for the word "game", the results are influenced much by electronical / PC games. But you'll also find dice, so it's close to what you have chosen already.

So, a concept draft for a logo (extra ugly here to not direct you too much) could be this:

[image: potential FindGamers logo]

Now, you choose how exactly the "finish" looks like. It could remain a plain black&white logo, which is ideal for printing on flyers. You could make it colourful to indicate joy. You could render it in 3D, ... - basically the rest is your decision.

You may try to replace "game" by "gamer", but don't get it confused with people search.

Comment: Your answer and Ryan's answer above makes sense.  However in the case of this site, the name isn't well known.  Your concept logo idea is the type of thing that actually fits the site well.  The word gamers can mean lots of things, so I think a graphic helps people visualize the point of a less known site.

Answer (score 3):

Like DA01 said you've got more of a banner than a logo currently. I think the best solution to indicate you're inclusive would be to have sections on your website for all of those items while not including an exhaustive number of graphics in what you're calling a logo.

The logo should be greatly simplified to something like Name and one maybe two identifiable objects. Perhaps the unifying thing in your case is dice or the tabletop or players. That's up to you to decide and then come up with a design for.

Consider other logos like Blizzard Entertainment:

[image]

Blizzard Entertainment is just their name. They don't show Orcs and Elves and stuff. They don't show that they have Strategy Games, Card Games, FPS shooters etc. They just show their name. Those other things are just present on their website and in their offerings.

Your logo needs to be like that. Show who you are on a broad sense. Leave the specifics to advertisements, hero graphics, sliders, and other content.